# Searchbar - search on 'enter' key

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm very new to Ionic framework.
Following the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/searchbar/Searchbar/) I created a searchbar like this:

```
<ion-searchbar
      [(ngModel)]="searchQuery"
      [showCancelButton]="true"
      (ionInput)="search($event)">
</ion-searchbar>
```

> ionInput   When the Searchbar input has changed including cleared.

This works as expected.

However I want a different behaviour. I don't want to trigger `search($event)` every time the input changes, but I couldn't find an [output event](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/searchbar/Searchbar/#output-events) that is emitted when the user hits the 'enter' key or clicks a button for example.

Is there a solution for this behaviour?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should be able to add Angular 2 keyup bindings to elements such as `keyup` and `click`

Template:

```
<ion-searchbar #q
      [showCancelButton]="true"
      (keyup.enter)="search(q.value)">
</ion-searchbar>
```

Component TS:

```
search(q: string) { 
    console.log(q); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With Ionic 5 using Angular you have to wrap the `ion-searchbar` inside a form tag like this:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="hideKeyboard()">
  <ion-searchbar (ionChange)="search($event)"></ion-searchbar>
</form>
```

In your component using Capacitor:

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { Keyboard } = Plugins;

...

hideKeyboard() {
  Keyboard.hide();
}
```

Of course you could use the ngSubmit event to also search and not only hide the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to capture 'Enter' key click or 'search' key click with `(search)` output event

```
<ion-searchbar
  (search)="search($event)">
</ion-searchbar>
```

Comment: This one works! @daniel-rubambura I couldn't find this in the official documentation. Is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @daniel-rubambura 's answer.

You can use `ngModel` in conjunction with `(search)` to get the value.

HTML

```
<ion-searchbar 
showCancelButton="never"
[(ngModel)]="searchTerm"
(search)="testFunc()"
></ion-searchbar>
```

.ts

```
searchTerm: string;
testFunc(){
    console.log(this.searchTerm);
  }
```